# Android Studio выбор SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

В android studio в sdk manager возможно установить сразу несколько версий. Долго гуглил, но так и не понял, какая версия активна при создании нового проекта? Как это определить? и где изменить?

Comment: Самая новая версия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию проект создается с максимальным значением SDK в targetSDK, compileSDK. minSDK запрашивается в процессе создания проекта.

Поменять все эти значения можно потом в build.gradle:
targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion

Answer (score 2):

> какая версия активна при создании нового проекта?

Вероятнее всего, самая новая, которая загружена.

> Как это определить? и где изменить?

В файле `build.gradle` в строке `compileSdkVersion`.